# Visual Studio slow with new ASP Core Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, visual-studio-2017

Everytime I try to create an ASP Core (.NET Framework, not the Core one) project, Visual Studio starts lagging even when the smallest action is performed.

For example: right clicking on the solution explorer, creating a new folder, creating views or controllers (It'll give some message about scaffolding), and even when I copy text (Formatting progress bar).
It literally takes 4 seconds to create a new folder or even open the context menu. On the other hand, on a "non-Core" project it is super fast.

I have the following plugins

- ReSharper Ultimate 2017.1.3
- Telerik DevCraft for students (not sure if this counts as a plugin tho)

and am running on this machine:

- CPU: I7-2630QM
- RAM: 16GB DDR3 1333MHz
- SSD: Crucial 250GB (CT250BX100SSD1)

Let me know if I need to provide any other detail. Thanks.